# After commit transaction doesn't refresh data C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

My program has an entity call `Articles`. In one form the user can specify how many new articles he wants to buy. This happens in a form called "Purchase order". So, when that happens, the stock musk increase. In another form, where I list all the articles, it must reflect that change.

Now, this is my problem. After I generate the purchase order, if I go to the SQL and I search that article in my DB, I can see the change. If go to my form, where I list the articles, I cant see that change. But, if I close the program and then I run it again, if I search the article, the change appears.

I don't know what could be the mistake. I'm using Entity Framework.

This is how I add the article.

```
BaseRepository.BeginTransaction();

foreach (Documento_Articulo doc in datos.Documento_Articulo)
{
    if (!articuloRepository.Increase(doc.Articulo.Id_Articulo, doc.Cantidad))
    {
        BaseRepository.RollBackTransaction();
        return response.Error("Error: - " + doc.Articulo.Descripcion);
    }
}

response.Value = documentoRepository.InsertGetDocument(datos);
BaseRepository.CommitTransaction();
```

I think that code does not have a problem, because as I say, I can see the change in my database.

Does anybody knows why this happens?

Comment: Did you refresh your list in code?

Comment: nope, my funcion retuns a list and I show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the client caches the results. If you set a breakpoint in the method which returns the list from the db, is it executed every time you display the it?